# Changes to persistence.xml ddl-generation take place only after second deployment

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, persistence, eclipselink

I have a maven build that creates an ear wich is deployed to Glassfish ESB v2.2. My problem is, that if I make changes to persistence.xml `eclipselink.ddl-generation` (let's say I change the value from `create-tables` to `drop-and-create-tables`) I need to deploy the ear twice in order for the changes to take effect.

Running:
maven 3.0.2
java 1.6.0_24
Glassfish ESB v2.2
Eclipselink 2.1.2

All though I'm not sure if the information above is relevant or not because if I recall right, we had similar problems with the same project back in the day when it was still an ant build and the persistence framework used was toplink.

I'm not exactly sure what kind of information I should attach to this question since I have absolutely no clue what might be causing this..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got an answer from Oracles Mitesh Meswani. Apparently the functionality is as expected.

"The behavior is as expected. When you specify drop-and-create-tables, the tables are dropped at undeploy of the app instance that was deployed with the option."